# Can I add a KeyListener to a UIPanel? Also in the WebUI?

Tags: jvx

If I type e.g.: the letter A then my registered action is called up

This does not seem to be the case.

```
…
panelMain.eventKeyPressed().addListener(this, "doPanelMainKeyPressed");
…

public void doPanelMainKeyPressed(UIKeyEvent event) throws Throwable 
{
        System.out.println("Key = " + event.getKeyChar() + "Code=" + event.getKeyCode());   
    buttonButton.requestFocus();
}
```

My doPanelMainKeyPressed isnt called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this isn't supported in every UI technology. It will work in desktop, but not in e.g. [reactUI](https://github.com/sibvisions/reactUI)

You should open a ticket for the UI.

Comment: ok clear. I will open a ticket.